# Installing UBUNTU on new HP laptop

Tags: 12.04

I'm very new to Ubuntu My new laptop(HP Pavlion) has Windows 7 with 1 partition C(597GB) And Windows Recover (3GB patition . it is full So i tried to partion again C to install ubuntu but it is immposible...So to could i install Ubuntu on same partion which is Windows located? Or is there any way to install it

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue I should warn you that HP removes any warraty (at least that was my personal experience in Mexico) after you touch the configuration they sold you ( Windows version, Partitions etc.)

In the case you don't care, use the official guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Windows